# Java Random Number Generator Display

Tags: java, random, arraylist

I have ran into a bit of trouble with some code i had to write for my course.

I had to write a random number generator which run's through the numbers one to fifty, ten thousand times and then only print out the top 15 highest occurring numbers. I have managed to do everything correctly except printing out the top 15 highest.

Here is my full block of code

```
package section4;
import java.util.Random;
public class Lottery {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int freq[] = new int[51];
        for(int roll = 1; roll<1000000;roll++){
            ++freq[1+rand.nextInt(50)];
        }
        System.out.println("Lottery Number\tFrequency");
        for(int face = 0; face<freq.length ;face++){
            System.out.println(face+"\t"+freq[face]);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using an ArrayList.

I first created the ArrayList and then added face and freq[face] to the arraylist and then printed the elements of the ArrayList. I tired it on a slim chance and as I thought I was wrong.

```
package section4;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lottery {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int freq[] = new int[51];


    ArrayList<Integer> top = new ArrayList<Integer>(15);

    for(int roll = 1; roll<1000000;roll++){
        ++freq[1+rand.nextInt(50)];
    }

    System.out.println("Lottery Number\tFrequency");

    for(int face = 0; face<freq.length ;face++){

        top.add(face);
        top.add(freq[face]);

        System.out.println(top);            
    }

}
}
```

And I have also tried to change the "For Statement" but I also knew that changing it to what I did only tells the compiler to run from 0 - 15 and not the full 50.

```
for(int face = 0; face< 15 ;face++){}
```

Can anyone help, as to how I can print out only the 15 highest, as I have been stuck on this for days.

Comment: use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` and associate each number with how many times it happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] b =Arrays.copyOf(freq, 5);    
 Arrays.sort(b);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++){
      System.out.println(b[50 - i]);
    }
```

Comment: This will lose the original index of each element. In other words, after sorting, you'll have no way of knowing which frequency had that count.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) to store the frequency as Key and number as the Value.  Then just iterate over the map in the order you want.